# How to do this program without a counter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lista = []
for i in range(5):
    i = int(input("Digite um valor para o vetor: "))
    lista = lista + [i]
x = int(input("Digite um valor para ver sua posição: "))
counter = 0
for j in range(5):
    if lista[j] == x:
    counter =+ 1
        print(j)
if counter == 0:
    print(x-1)
```

In the above program you put any 5 numbers in the list, then you look for the position of the number you inputted in the list, if the number inputted is not in the list it will print `x-1`.

For example `List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

`x = 5`  then it will print 5

`x = 7` it will print 6

How do I make it print `x-1` without counter? I tried using:

```
else:
    print(x-1)
```

but then it will print `x-1` 5 times, I only want to print it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a counter at all, as you're only using it to check that there were no matches. You can use the `for..else` structure to check whether the loop completed without exiting from a `break`.

```
for j in range(5):
    if lista[j] == x:
        print(j)
        break
else:
    print(x-1)
```

If you want to print each index that matches your search query, I would move to a different approach:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> print(*(i for i,v in enumerate(map(int, input('Enter values separated by space:\n').split())) if v==x))
Enter values separated by space:
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 2 3 4
>>> print(*(i for i,v in enumerate(map(int, input('Enter values separated by space:\n').split())) if v==x))
Enter values separated by space:
2 2 1 10 1
2 4
>>> print(*(i for i,v in enumerate(map(int, input('Enter values separated by space:\n').split())) if v==x))
Enter values separated by space:
2 2 1 10
2
```

Comment: Thanks I knew there was a more simple way idk how I didnt think of that

Comment: But then If I make a list [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] and x = 1

Comment: It will print only 0 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, anyway I can fix that?

Comment: @Nibaga - That sounds like a different challenge than what you describe in your question. I would use a different approach for that, as shown in the edit.